# I am trying to recreate this R logic within a SQL query. Any ideas on how I should go about doing so? Appreciate any assistance at all

Tags: sql, r, databricks

This is the R script that I am attempting to recreate using a CASE WHEN statement in SQL:

```r
dat[ ,X_1_7_Spline := pmax(1,pmin(ifelse(is.na(X),1,X),7))]
```

It seems that this command is telling the parser to return the parallel maxima of a vector containing a conditional statement as long as the value of variable X lies between 1 and the parallel minima of some value and 7 (as long as the value is not null). It then seems to join the new column containing these values back to the original dataset (dat). I am having some troubles representing the "pmax(1,pmin(ifelse(is.na(X),1,X),7))" portion of the code in my SQL query and would appreciate any ideas on how I might be able to do this effectively.

I have something very remedial right now, which I know does not express this above statement properly:

```sql
CASE WHEN MAX(IF(ISNOTNULL(X) AND MIN(X)=1 AND MAX(X)=7) then 1 else X end as X_1_7_Spline
```

Any thoughts/feedback would be greatly appreciated as I am still trying to understand the R script. Thanks in advance for any insight on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ifelse(is.na(X),1,X)` can be translated into SQL's `COALESCE(X, 1)`; and
- `pmin` and `pmax` logic can be placed in a `CASE WHEN` (as you've started)

Perhaps this?

```sql
CASE WHEN X < 1 THEN 1
  WHEN X > 7 THEN 7
  ELSE coalesce(X, 1) END as NewX
```

We don't need to worry about `coalesce`ing the `X < 1` or `X > 7` because `null < 1` does not resolve as true, so it does not accept that case.

Demo in R using `sqldf`:

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(X = c(-1,5,9,NA))
dat[, X_1_7_Spline := pmax(1,pmin(ifelse(is.na(X),1,X),7)) ]
sqldf::sqldf("select *, (CASE WHEN X < 1 THEN 1 WHEN X > 7 THEN 7 ELSE coalesce(X,1) END) as NewX from dat")
#    X X_1_7_Spline NewX
# 1 -1            1    1
# 2  5            5    5
# 3  9            7    7
# 4 NA            1    1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, r2evans! I think your first solution is something along the lines of what I need for this. I would just like to clarify that I am not actually using R in any capacity, but am simply attempting to "translate" R script into arguments within a SQL query. Apologies for any confusion. I know this may seem a bit strange, but I appreciate your response.

Comment: I think I may have found a viable solution, but am not sure how to put this in terms of a CASE WHEN statement or if this is even needed: GREATEST(1,LEAST(IF(ISNULL(X) THEN 1 ELSE X), 7)) as X_1_7_Spline. Maybe cast a new variable called XY from var X using this?

Comment: I don't understand: the answer (first code block) is all SQL. The second coffee block is just one way to show that it works. *Did you try it with your database,?*

Comment: My apologies, I meant the first block. Unfortunately I am just assisting another individual with this task so I was not able to personally test it but I believe that your solution should work just fine. Thank you for your time, r2evans!

Comment: and for the record, I typed that last comment early in the morning before I had had any coffee, as should be readily apparent by my autotypo "coffee block" vs "code block". \*sigh\*

Comment: I was wondering where that came from haha. I was searching for "coffee block" in Google before I was able to have my own coffee...